# How can I pass an image file if I have the image's content uri?

Tags: android, image, file, kotlin, uri

I want to use a resize library to compress some photos. The library requires me to pass to it the source file. I am choosing the image with a simpe intent, and what I get in return is a content Uri like this one:

`content://com.google.android.apps.photos.contentprovider/-1/1/content%3A%2F%2Fmedia%2Fexternal%2Fimages%2Fmedia%2F96/ORIGINAL/NONE/2013194373`

But when I place it inside `File()` it crashes with the following error
`Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.graphics.Bitmap.getWidth()' on a null object reference`

How can I convert this content uri to a valid path for the file function?
I have tried playing with Uri.parse in different ways but couldn't figure it out.

I also tried to mess around with the content resolver but couldn't understand how to make that work wither.

I wold appreciate help in Kotlin if possible but will probably understand it in Java too.

Comment: you cannot convert `Uri` to `File` - however you can "convert" it to `InputStream` - refer again to `ContentResolver` documentation for more info

Comment: I've been able to get the input stream like this `val myInputStream = activity!!.contentResolver.openInputStream(Uri.parse(localImagePost.imageUri))` but I can't find the method that would allow me to convert that into a file path

Comment: you cannot get any "file path", what do you need it for?

Comment: I am using an image picker for the user to choose an image. That image would then be resized before uploading, but the code that I am using to resize it requires me to pass to it a the file. I am using the code successfully when taking photos and resizing immediately but that's because I have a hold of the new file.

Comment: what "image resizing" code do you mean?

Comment: Specifically I am using this library https://github.com/hkk595/Resizer

Comment: so you have to change [this](https://github.com/hkk595/Resizer/blob/master/app/src/main/java/me/echodev/resizer/util/ImageUtils.java#L34) line in order to use `InputStream` instead of `File`

Comment: and [here](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/03/15/how-consume-content-uri.html) and [here](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/07/04/uri-not-necessarily-file.html) you can read why you cannot get "file path" from your `Uri` - do not even try several "getRealFilePathFromUri()" methods that are posted here again and again (i saw maybe 20 variants and none was working correctly - they are just workarounds working if you have good luck)

Comment: Appreciate the help pskink. Just as you've posted you second last comment I was able to solve my issue using `FileUtils.copyInputStreamToFile`

Comment: I would love to do it in the best way possible, didn't realize this would not be a good solution. I'm not sure if I got your solution with using the bitmap line. I give the Resizer a Bitmap instead of File? I'll try that to see if I can make it to work

Comment: [here](https://github.com/hkk595/Resizer/blob/master/app/src/main/java/me/echodev/resizer/util/ImageUtils.java#L34) they are using `BitmapFactory.decodeFile()` method - simply change it to `BitmapFactory.decodeStream()` - that way you dont need to create any temporary file, copy the content with `FileUtils.copyInputStreamToFile()` and then delete it afterwards

Answer (score 0):

I found this before some time (I don't remember where)

```
private fun getRealPathFromUri(context: Context, contentUri: Uri): String {
    var cursor: Cursor? = null
    try {
        val proj = arrayOf(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA)
        cursor = context.contentResolver.query(contentUri, proj, null, null, null)
        val columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA)
        cursor.moveToFirst()
        return cursor.getString(columnIndex)
    } finally {
        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.close()
        }
    }
}
```

Call it like this

```
val file = File(getRealPathFromUri(context, uri))
```